# 3-promise rule for functions

Tags: c++

I need help remembering what book I read this from, It might have been Effective C++ or something, but I don't remember. I was reading something that basically stated that functions have 3 promises:

1. Validate input parameters to make sure they meet the expected input requirements
2. Guaranteed to respect & maintain invariants
3. Validate output parameters (returns & out params)

The book also had some nice names for this but for the life of me I don't remember. It bothered me enough that I had to come to Stackoverflow to see if someone might recognize this and help me remember...

Comment: I can't imagine what book might have said this!  It's common practice in C++ (and C) to place the burden on the user of the function to ensure inputs are valid.  And I don't know what "validate output parameters" would mean.

Comment: @Oli: I'm asking this question because I don't know what book it's from, so how would I be able to tell you? :( Also if you are placing the burden on the user, you will end up breaking invariants and have general stability issues.

Comment: @Robert: Like I said, placing the burden (of ensuring input conditions) on the user/client of the function is pretty standard in C++!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: how could having the caller be responsible for input validation ever be a good idea?  The function has no control over the caller, so therefore it has no control over the validity of the input.  Input validation must occur in the function, not the caller.  The alternative makes no sense (resource and performance constraints permitting).

Comment: @siride It makes a lot of sense. Many conditions simply cannot be checked in the called function.

Comment: @siride: Not only what @Neil said, but also for speed.  The author of the function documents his/her assumptions, and it is up to the client to ensure that they honour those assumptions.  (`memcpy` not checking for `NULL` inputs is one such example).

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: if they can't be checked, they can't be checked.  Fine.  Having a general principle of not validating input that *can* be validated seems to me to a be sure way to create a vector for subtle and not-so-subtle bugs.  It's contrary to the general ideas of defensive programming.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: that would fall under my "resource and performance constraints permitting" clause.

Comment: @siride I'm not sure I believe in defensive programming - it usually ends up being an exercise in bug-hiding, in my experience.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: sure, if you just silently "fix" the offending input and move on.  But if you throw exceptions or in some other way indicate that there is a problem, then you are not hiding.  Moreover, you guarantee that the problem will be revealed, whereas not checking might allow a case where the input is invalid but due to the particulars of the algorithm (or bugs), the functions ends up "working", or at least not failing spectacularly.  You want to talk about bug-hiding, that's it right there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of the concept is [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract):

> - Expect a certain condition to be guaranteed on entry by any client module that calls it: the routine's precondition—an obligation for the client, and a benefit for the supplier (the routine itself), as it frees it from having to handle cases outside of the precondition.
> - Guarantee a certain property on exit: the routine's postcondition—an obligation for the supplier, and obviously a benefit (the main benefit of calling the routine) for the client.
> - Maintain a certain property, assumed on entry and guaranteed on exit: the class invariant.

Comment: @Robert Notice this does NOT say that the function should check the pre and post conditions.

Comment: @Robert The quote is from Wikipedia. I don't know the book you're talking about, but you can find about this concept (suggested by Bertrand Meyer, the creator of the Eiffel language) in most of the modern software design books.

Comment: After reading this a bit closer you are correct Neil. However, this sounds incredibly familiar. However, I can't say I agree with it. If the function does not validate the input, then the user could break class invariants. The function has to either correct the input or reject it (with an exception, for example). The function ultimately is required to maintain the contracts for preconditions & postconditions.

Comment: @Robert: If the user breaks preconditions, then *they* have broken the "contract".  The function promises to honour the invariant *if* the input conditions are met.

Comment: @Oli, the function isn't promising anything if it doesn't take control of its input parameters. Saying that it only honors the invariant if the input conditions are met is the same as saying it doesn't do anything at all. In fact, the function would have no concept of invariants. Allowing the user full control over this is flawed and can break class state. Functions must enforce the invariants, otherwise if you unit test a class (for example) you would not be able to create a test case which fails.

Comment: @Robert: Of course the function is promising something!  The purpose of a unit test is to verify that the function behaves as expected within its specified input domain.  (Don't get me wrong, I'm not suggesting that having e.g. `assert`s in your function is a bad thing, only that it's not a mandatory thing, in this framework at least.)

Comment: @Robert: (cont.) Another way to think about it is that input validation logic inside your function is really a test that the client code is sound; this is orthogonal to the purpose of unit tests.

Comment: @Oli, this article talks about what I am an advocate of. See the "Explicit Contracts" section: http://tinyurl.com/325jeo

Comment: @Oli, On the contrary, unit tests (in this case) are there to test your pre-conditions (amongst other things). It tries to circumvent your function's validation of your input parameters to see if it can break your invariants.

Comment: @Robert: I still disagree.  Take `sqrt` as an example.  If your function does not claim to offer any particular behaviour for negative input values, then what do you gain by writing a unit test that injects negative numbers?  However, if your function claims to throw an exception on negative input, then you should of course unit test that to demonstrate that it correctly does so.  Put another way, input validation is part of the specified behaviour of your function; it it exists, you should test it; if there is none, then you don't need to test it!

Comment: @Oli For your `sqrt` example, I would put a debug assert at the top of the function body that would check if the value is less than 0. Then, I would write my unit test in such a way that it checks for the assert. In other cases, you might also throw an exception & test that, however for this particular example you wouldn't want to do that for performance reasons.

Comment: @Oli (cont): You do not want to leave your function open to potential improper usage. If you simply rely on your imaginary pre-conditions & lazy programmers on your team just throw in a value that is negative, this might result in a buffer overrun, or other types of bugs that could affect the security of the application. Everything must be tested!! It simply doesn't make sense to have use-cases untested!

Comment: @Robert: Yes, but what is your list of use-cases?  It's very rarely the set of all conceivable inputs.  If you're explicitly writing a validation routine (e.g. for sanitising user input from an HTML form), then the input domain is indeed the set of all conceivable inputs.  But that doesn't apply to all functions, unless you choose it to be so.  It may be perfectly acceptable for your `sqrt` documentation to say "This function calculates the square root for all non-negative input values.".

Comment: @Robert: (cont.) If the calling code breaks that contract, that's their fault.  If you choose to be nice and add an (undocumented) assert inside `sqrt`, then that's a test of the calling code.  IMHO.